# Passing JSON data from WP Query into AJAX causing NULL errors

Tags: php, wp-query, ajax, json

I am currently using a `WP_Query` that'll trigger from an AJAX call when a button is pressed. The post meta fields `lat` `lng` will be used as location data for a google map. The query outputs fine without AJAX but cannot seem to get it to return the results with it.

The response I receive - `[{name: "", lng: null, lat: null}, {name: "", lng: null, lat: null}]`

Now I believe the error is when transforming the results into JSON at `json_encode` stage, but not too sure? Any help would be great, fairly new to AJAX!

**Function.php**

```
<?php
//Search Function

function ek_search(){
    $args = array(
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => $_POST['date'], 
        'post_type' => 'property',
        'posts_per_page' => 20,
        'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'after' => $_POST['property_added']
        ),
    ),
    );

$query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
$posts = $query->get_posts();   

foreach( $posts as $post ) {
     $locations[] = array(
       "name" => get_the_title(),
       "lng" => get_field('loc_lng'),
       "lat" => get_field('loc_lat')
     );
 }     

$location = json_encode($locations);

echo $location;

die();

}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ek_search', 'ek_search' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ek_search', 'ek_search' );
```

**Form**

```
<form id="filter">

<button>Search</button>
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="ek_search">

</form>
```

**JS**

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#filter').submit(function(){
        var filter = $('#filter');
        var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php", null); ?>';
        data = { action: "ek_search"};
        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,
            data:data,
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);  
            }

        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you considered using a REST API endpoint instead? You wouldn't even need to json encode, echo and call die, it's all taken care of for you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Admin-AJAX is not optimized for JSON. If you need your answer to be in JSON, use the REST-API instead. This API generates JSON response by default.

All you have to do is to register a rest route, and access the URL:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    //Path to REST route and the callback function
    register_rest_route( 'scopeak/v2', '/my_request/', array(
            'methods' => 'POST', 
            'callback' => 'my_json_response' 
    ) );
});
```

Now, the callback function:

```
function my_json_response(){
    $args = array(
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => $_POST['date'], 
        'post_type' => 'property',
        'posts_per_page' => 20,
        'date_query' => array(
            array(
                'after' => $_POST['property_added']
            ),
        ),
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
    if($query->have_posts()){
        while($query->have_posts()){
        $query->the_post();
            $locations[]['name'] = get_the_title();
            $locations[]['lat'] = get_field('loc_lng');
            $locations[]['lng'] = get_field('loc_lat');
        }
    }
    //Return the data
    return $locations;
}
```

Now, you can get your JSON response by visiting the following URL:

```
wp-json/scopeak/v2/my_json_response/
```

For testing purposes, you can change `POST` method to `GET` and directly access this URL. If you get a response, then change it back to `POST` and work on your javascript.

That's all.

Comment: Thanks for the more up to date API approach, definitely want to use this method! I got a response ok but still displaying null in the fields. If I use that exact query within the page template it outputs the JSON fine so not sure what's causing it still. Any ideas?

Comment: @scopeak You're welcome. Admin-AJAX comes in handy when you need to echo your content for some reason, otherwise REST is more efficient. Have you tried and accessing the URL directly? If you get an answer this way, then the problem is with the jQuery AJAX. Please let me know about this.

Comment: Yep, sorry I've accessed the URL directly with `wp-json/scopeak/v2/my_request` using the identical code you provided. And it spits out the usual [{"name":""},{"lat":null},{"lng":null},]

Comment: @JackJohansson you shouldn't use POST or GET directly in a REST callback, you should use the request object passed as a parameter to the callback instead

Comment: Also the loop was missing a `the_post` call

Comment: @scopeak I didn't notice you are using `foreach` instead of `while`. If you want to use functions such as `get_the_title()`, you need to set up the post's data by using `setup_postdata()` before you do that. I updated the code so the functions would work properly.

Comment: @TomJNowell Yes thank you I just noticed the loop and updated.

Comment: Dang! That's it :) Thanks guys can't believe I missed that I used `foreach` instead of `while` Now onto the AJAX, will mark as solved for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, how are you getting the `$_POST` variables? you have to pass them in your `data` object on your ajax call. Example:

```
jQuery(function($){
$('#filter').submit(function(){
    var filter = $('#filter');
    var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php", null); ?>';
    data = { action: 'ek_search', date: date, property_added: property};
    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        data:data,
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);  
        }

    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

See this [Article](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/using-ajax-with-wordpress/) for reference.

Comment: I had tried to do `data = { action: 'ek_search', name: name, lat: lat, lng: lng};` but spat out an error saying lat doesn't exist. Is that correct to reference the $_POST variables?

Comment: You have to pass trough the `data` object any values that you will use in the `action`. In your code you're trying to get two parameters in the `$_POST`, the `$_POST['date']` and `$_POST['property_added']`, you have to pass them trough the ajax call.

Comment: I updated my answer with a post showing an example.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I am really sorry for responding a little late.

Second, you need to get the values of your form by using the serialize method, Please check the below example.

```
<form id="filter">

<input type="button" name="smt" value="Submit" id="smt" />
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="ek_search">

</form>


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var form=$("#filter");
$("#smt").click(function(){
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:form.attr("action"),
    data:form.serialize(),
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);  
    }
});
});
});
</script>
```