# Go to / Scroll to Password Field on WordPress Posts After Submit With Message(s)

Tags: php, posts, the-content, password

I have, based on post category, added a password form (shortcode) whereof the purpose is to hide certain HTML code.

To do this, I have wrapped certain HTML-tags in a shortcode using the `the_content` filter.

The password itself is added through an array, which would be much better suited as an global setting through the WP admin settings page - but that's a different story.

**My main problem is this;** after submitting the password - no matter if the password is right or wrong - the user get "scrolled" all the way to the top of the page.

That should not happen, which is why I added a ID to the form. Upon submitting the correct password, the user should be kept in the same place, which is where the form was which is where the HTML code now is.

Makes sense? Part of the problem is this; there's no message for "password successful" or "incorrect password".

As you can see in the code, I've already tried to add the ID to the path using this:
`path=/#functioncode` without success.

**This is the full code:**

```
add_shortcode( 'protected', 'protected_html' );
function protected_html( $atts, $content=null ) {

    $functionUserPassword = isset( $_REQUEST['password']) ? $_REQUEST['password'] : ( isset( $_COOKIE['functionUserPassword']) ? $_COOKIE['functionUserPassword'] : NULL );

        if ( in_array( $functionUserPassword, array('password') ) ) {

            $return_html_content = do_shortcode($content);
    
        } else {

    $return_html_content = 
    
        '<div id="functioncode" style="margin-top:20px;font-size:15px;">To view the content of this section, submit your password.</div>
        <form method="post" onsubmit="functionCookie(this); return false;">
        <input required style="display: block; width: 69%; height: 50px; margin-right: 1%; float: left; border: 2px solid #333;" type="text" placeholder="&#32;Password Here" name="password" id="functionUserPassword">
        <input style="display: block; margin: 0px; width: 30%; height: 50px; background-color: #333; color: #fff;" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>

        <script>
        
            function functionCookie(form){
        
            document.cookie = "functionUserPassword=" + escape(form.functionUserPassword.value) + "; path=/#functioncode";
        
        </script>';
    }

    return $return_html_content;
}
```

**Here's the code which I am using with the content filter:**

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wrap_html_in_shortcode', 9 );
function wrap_html_in_shortcode( $content ) {

    if ( ! in_category( 'premium' ) ) return $content;

    $content = preg_replace('/(<span[^>]*>\s*<div[^>]*>)/',"[protected]$1", $content);

    $content = preg_replace('/(<\/div>\s*<\/span>)/', "$1[/protected]", $content);

    return $content;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using AJAX to achieve this? Seems like the perfect case to go for it. You can send the HTML content back by the server, and replace the current content using AJAX/jQuery.

Comment: Ok, can you provide an example code?

Comment: [This](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/272053/94498) can be a good place to start.

Comment: Actually @HaroldAldersen, I noticed that your form was not supposed to be submitted because you've got that `return false` in the `onsubmit` tag; however, your JS has a syntax error - the function `functioncode` is never closed, i.e. it's missing the `}`.

Comment: Thank you all so far. I will make changes and test them out and get back to you.

Comment: I mean, the function name is `functionCookie`...

Comment: I closed the JS function and changed the input into `<form method="post" onsubmit="event.preventDefault();functionCookie(this);">` and yet, no change.

Comment: @HaroldAldersen, you should tag the user that you're replying to so that (s)he gets notified of your reply. But anyway, explain the "no change" - what should've changed that still didn't change? And please edit your question and include the code you're currently using as well as the ones you've tried after the answers were posted - don't change the question's context, but append your updates at the bottom.

Comment: @SallyCJ No change = none of the code given in any of the answers here work. The page still reloads / fresh after submitting the password which means; "scroll" to top.

Comment: Well, I made a [Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/1fyikp9Er1q0nJZC) based on the same `onsubmit` code as the original in question, and after closing the custom function, the page no longer reloads.

Comment: @SallyCJ Ok, there's no actual password to test with nor is there any content to be displayed after submitting a correct password. All I get is a cookie notice.

Please change my original code so that I can test it locally. I did copy your JS code and nothing changed.

Comment: Yes there's no actual content or password validation, because I just wanted to show you the page does not get reloaded upon submitting the form, unless if: 1) There's an error in the JS script. 2) There's another JS which forces the form submission the normal way which triggers a page reload. 3) JavaScript is disabled in the browser.

Comment: @SallyCJ nope, none of that. I closed the function in the code on my test server, so that's not an issue anymore. But still, on desktop and mobile, the page is reloaded / refreshed no matter what version of all the answers from here I use.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119970/discussion-between-sally-cj-and-harold-aldersen).

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to do and this doesn't look like a WordPress issue, but submitting a html form will certainly lead to a new page load. So what you want is redirect not to the same page (which happens when you specify no action, leading the page to scroll to the top) but to an anchor on that page. The [usual way to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8395269/what-do-form-action-and-form-method-post-action-do) is to include it in the `action` variable of your `form` like this:

```
<a name="somewhere"></a>

<form method="POST" action="#somewhere">
  ...
</form>
```

Comment: Okay. I'll check and try.

Comment: No, sorry. No matter what I do, the page reloads / refreshes.

Comment: Yes, that's what i said in my answer. Submitting a form inevitably leads to a page reload.

Comment: This solution should work, did you have any success Harold?

Comment: @keepkalm no, the page reloads / refreshes. I needed to avoid that, which is what my question is about. I understand now that I need to use AJAX, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly advise you to break out the js code rather than having it in HTML attributes, it's just so much more readable.

However, as you've written it, this should fix your problem:

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="event.preventDefault();functionCookie(this);">
```

The default action for a form, when it's submitted (the "event" in the code above) is for the form to be, well, submitted!

So, you need to cancel that default action using "preventDefault".

Comment: What is "event"?

Comment: event is what has been triggered.....

Comment: Yes, I know. But OP or other readers may not know, and you should explain why would `event.preventDefault()` fix the problem, when the original code actually used `return false`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the solution that you need:

```
<input onclick="window.location.href = '/#functioncode';" type="submit" value="Submit request" />
```

Found in a different stack. Normally I use this to redirect to a 'Thank You' page to track conversions, but it should work equally well with your anchor.

Here's what it looks like in your full code:

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="functionCookie(this); return false;">
  <input required style="display: block; width: 69%; height: 50px; margin-right: 1%; float: left; border: 2px solid #333;" type="text" placeholder="&#32;Password Here" name="password" id="functionUserPassword">
  <input style="display: block; margin: 0px; width: 30%; height: 50px; background-color: #333; color: #fff;" type="submit" value="Submit">
  <input onclick="window.location.href = '/#functioncode';" type="submit" value="Submit request" />
</form>
```

Comment: Using cPanel and using your code to replace mine, the editor shows an error. This line is not properly formatted: `<input onclick="window.location.href = '/#functioncode';" type="submit" value="Submit request" />`  and also, why two `type` and `value` ?

I tried fixing it myself by just adding `onclick="window.location.href = "/#functioncode"` to the existing input - but the end result is the same - reload / refresh.

Comment: Try it with the full URL and anchor. That should work. It is always going to refresh/reload because that is how forms work. Check the URL in the browser and see what it says.